# Increment through items by updating the ref()

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

The app state

```
this.state = {
   text: "",
   loading: false,
   currentNum: 0
};
```

I'm initially fetching the first item from the database. Since `currentNum: 0`, the first item is correctly rendered.

```
componentWillMount() {

   let inititialLoad = true;
   this.setState({ loading: true });

   firebase.database().ref(this.state.currentNum).on("value", snapshot => {
      this.setState({ text: snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().text });
      if (inititialLoad) {
         this.setState({ loading: false });
         inititialLoad = false;
      }
   });

}
```

I then added a button

```
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.nextData}>
    <View>
      <Text>Next text</Text>
    </View>
  </TouchableOpacity>
```

with an onPress function to add one to `currentNum`

```
nextData() {

   this.setState({
      currentNum: this.state.currentNum + 1
   });

   firebase.database().ref(this.state.currentNum).on("value", snapshot => {
      this.setState({ text: snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().text });
   });

}
```

My data tree in firbase realtime database is :

[image]

The problem I'm facing is that when I press the button the index is correctly incremented but the data fetching seems to be shifted.

When

`currentNum: 0 
Text: FirstText`

`currentNum: 1
Text: FirstText`

`currentNum: 2
Text: SecondText`

So I initially have to press the button twice to start going through the items one by one.

Is there something missing in my code? Or am I using the wrong approach to increment using ref()?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setState` is async , you can pass a callback to `setState` that will be executed after the state changes

so what you can do is

```
this.setState({
    currentNum: this.state.currentNum + 1
}, () =>
{
    firebase.database().ref(this.state.currentNum).on("value", snapshot =>
    {
        this.setState({text: snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().text});
    });
});
```